# Run management commands on Django server in a Linux hosted App Service in Azure. Anything other than cronjobs?

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

Please Excuse me if this question has been posted before.I have a linux hosted App Service in Azure running a Django server. I want to run a management command periodically on the server. I am somewhat of an inexperienced person as far as cloud and architechure goes. So please be as elaborate as possible, mentioning the reasoning behind your recomendations, so that I can learn more.

- Tried using Cronjobs but it was not consistent and I did not have access to logs.
- Can't use Webjobs since the app service is on a linux machine and webjobs aren't supported on linux machines.
- Have read that funtions can be used. If so please point me in the right direction on how to setup and connect function to the App service and run command.
- The app code base is implemented in github and I am using github action for CI/CD Integration.

Attaching below the yaml file generated in Azure portal

```
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - AppName

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - prod
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            .
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'AppName'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ <Appservice secret> }}
```

Comment: please  share How did you provide How did you configure the app and share the code used

Comment: @Sampath Have added configuration information and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I **deployed** one **Django app in Azure Web app** and then ustilized **Azure Functions to run one management command** and **integrated Azure Functions as API with Azure APIM service** and **added the APIM service Functions API to my Azure web app** to perform the commands, Refer below:-*

I followed the MSDOC for deploying the Python Django web app with [PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=django%2Cwindows&pivots=azure-developer-cli)
to Azure App [Service](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-azure-app-service/) .

- Change database details in `settings .py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DBNAME'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DBHOST'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DBUSER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DBPASS'),
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'},
    }
}
```

- set `SECRET_KEY` and Database details in env before running the application

**Local:**
[image]

[image]

- Deployed the code Using GitHub Actions to [Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/python-web-app-github-actions-app-service?tabs=azure-cli)

[image]

**Work Flow status:**

[image]

- Add the env variable in [Configuration](https://i.imgur.com/KN1Zk7o.png) and open SSH to perform migration operation.

[image]

[image]

***Now, I created one Azure Function that performs the management commands like below:-***

**Run management commands on Azure function:**

- The code below creates a folder with a specified name sent in the HTTP request body

```py
def  main(req:  func.HttpRequest)  ->  func.HttpResponse:

try:

req_body = req.get_json()

folder_name = req_body.get('folder_name',  'default_folder')

  

if  not  folder_name:

return  func.HttpResponse("Folder name is missing in the request body.",  status_code=400)

  

os.makedirs(folder_name)

return  func.HttpResponse(f"Folder '{folder_name}' created successfully.",  status_code=200)

except  Exception  as  e:

return  func.HttpResponse(f"Error creating folder: {str(e)}",  status_code=500)
```

[image]

[image]

- Created an API in Azure API [Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish) and the function [app](https://i.imgur.com/dBYD0EL.png).

[image]

[image]

- Select the API created in the web app in `API management`

[image]

- **References:-** [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-app-service) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958393/how-can-i-import-azure-api-app-in-azure-api-management)